# Find and Replace text that is within double quotes with VBA

Tags: regex, t-sql, ms-access, vba

I’m looking for a way to find and replace in VBA that only looks at text within double quotes and handles all occurrences.

I am writing a SQL parser that will convert Access Jet SQL statements into T-SQL for SQL Server.  One of the hang-ups I have is converting double quotes into single quotes when single quotes are part of literal output.

I had been using `SQL = Replace(SQL, """", "'")` until I came across some legitimate single quotes embedded in strings, which will get messed up by that command.

For example, if the SQL statement in Access is `SELECT "Kat's code is righteous"`

The Replace() function will end up converting this to `SELECT 'Kat's code is righteous'`  which results in an extra single quote that T-SQL won't like.

I'm looking for a function that will return `SELECT 'Kat''s code is righteous'` so it will work in T-SQL.

I started by looking for a RegEx solution and then decided it may be too complicated so I started writing a function that looped through each character in the string.  A challenge is that eventually I was going to use the VBA Replace() function and it doesn't report how many times it made a replace, so after the replace I wasn't sure how much to move the loop index to search for the next match. Now I'm leaning back on RegEx but am not sure in VBA how to have it replace text within each matched result and minimize the chance of it corrupting the string.  I've tried a RegEx pattern of `"([^"]*)"` but not sure how to make it only find matches that contain a single quote.   Example: https://regexr.com/483n9

I've loaded a sample SQL select statement into a variable for testing:

```vb
Public Sub Test_ReplaceInQuotes()

    Dim sTest As String

    sTest = "SELECT ""Kat's code is righteous."", left(""abc"",1), right('source code',4), ""Aaron's code has been righteous too."", ""Kat's code is righteous."", ""Right answer is '"" & Table.RightAnswer & ""'"""
    Debug.Print "Access:", sTest

    Debug.Print "Converted:", ReplaceInQuotes(sTest, "'", "''")
    'Debug.Print "Converted:", ReplaceInQuotes(sTest, "code", "source code") ' <- Make sure a longer replacement string doesn't break it.
    'Debug.Print "Converted:", ReplaceInQuotes(sTest, "right", "hid") ' <- Make sure it doesn't mess up the right() function.

    ' In another part of my parser I will replace ALL double quotes with single quotes, and & with +.
    Debug.Print "Final TSQL:", replace(ReplaceInQuotes(sTest, "'", "''"), """", "'")
End Sub
```

This is the output I expect it to generate:

```SQL
Access:       SELECT "Kat's code is righteous.", left("abc",1), right('source code',4), "Aaron's code has been righteous too.", "Kat's code is righteous.", "Right answer is '" & Table.RightAnswer & "'"
Converted:    SELECT "Kat''s code is righteous.", left("abc",1), right('source code',4), "Aaron''s code has been righteous too.", "Kat''s code is righteous.", "Right answer is ''" & Table.RightAnswer & "''"
Final TSQL:   SELECT 'Kat''s code is righteous.', left('abc',1), right('source code',4), 'Aaron''s code has been righteous too.', 'Kat''s code is righteous.', 'Right answer is ''' & Table.RightAnswer & ''''
```

A nuance of Jet SQL is that it allows literal strings to be wrapped in single or double quotes, such as `In ('ab',"cd", 'efg')`.  T-SQL only accepts strings in single quotes.

Comment: Can't you just trim the existing qualifiers, replace escaped `""` with `"`, escape `'` with `''`, then re-qualify it by enclosing it in single quotes?

Comment: I tried what I think you are suggesting, but it converts `right('source code',4)` into `right(''source code'',4)`.  That's a side effect of the nuance I mentioned.

Comment: In that case, you'll probably want to "scan" the character array simultaneously from both right and left to find the enclosure.  Once you have that, the replace method would work on the sub-string, no?

Comment: Are you suggesting that there cannot be two single quotes inside double quotes i.e. **"Kat's  code is Aaron's code."** cannot happen i.e. how do you decide that **'source code'** stays **'source code'**?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this approach.

```
Public Sub Test_ReplaceInQuotes()

    Dim sTest As String
    Dim Sp() As String
    Dim p As Integer, q As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

    sTest = "SELECT ""Kat's code is righteous."", left(""abc"",1), right('source code',4), ""Aaron's code has been righteous too."", ""Kat's code is righteous."", ""Right answer is '"" & Table.RightAnswer & ""'"""
'    Debug.Print "Access:", sTest
    Sp = Split(sTest, ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(Sp)
        p = InStr(Sp(i), "('")
        If p Then
            If Right(Trim(Sp(i)), 1) = "'" Then
                Sp(i) = Left(Sp(i), p) & Chr(34) & Mid(Sp(i), p + 2)
                For q = Len(Sp(i)) To 1 Step -1
                    If Mid(Sp(i), q, 1) = "'" Then
                        Sp(i) = Left(Sp(i), q - 1) & Chr(34) & Mid(Sp(i), q + 1)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next q
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Debug.Print Replace(Replace(Join(Sp, ","), "'", "''"), Chr(34), "'")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution based on RegEx:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim s As String
    Dim r As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim m As Object

    s = "SELECT ""Kat's code is righteous."", left(""abc"",1), right('source code',4), ""Aaron's code has been righteous too."", ""Kat's code is righteous."", ""Right answer is '"" & Table.RightAnswer & ""'"""
    r = ""
    i = 1
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "('(?:''|[^'])*')|(""[^""]*"")"
        For Each m In .Execute(s)
            With m
                If .SubMatches(1) <> "" Then
                    r = r & Mid(s, i, .FirstIndex + 1 - i)
                    r = r & Replace(Replace(Mid(s, .FirstIndex + 1, .Length), "'", "''"), """", "'")
                Else
                    r = r & Mid(s, i, .FirstIndex + 1 + .Length - i)
                End If
                i = .FirstIndex + 1 + .Length
            End With
        Next
    End With
    If i <= Len(s) Then r = r & Mid(s, i, Len(s) - i + 1)
    Debug.Print s
    Debug.Print r

End Sub
```

The output is as follows:

```
SELECT "Kat's code is righteous.", left("abc",1), right('source code',4), "Aaron's code has been righteous too.", "Kat's code is righteous.", "Right answer is '" & Table.RightAnswer & "'"
SELECT 'Kat''s code is righteous.', left('abc',1), right('source code',4), 'Aaron''s code has been righteous too.', 'Kat''s code is righteous.', 'Right answer is ''' & Table.RightAnswer & ''''
```